# Relationship between dateformatter, time zone and language

Tags: iphone, ios, timezone, nsdateformatter

The language of the time formatter could not be changed as shown in the following two screen shot. Both language are set to English. One time zone is Beijing-China, the other one is Louisville-U.S.A.. 
[image][image]

In my app, the `NSDateFormatter` is created as following codes:

```
NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dMMM HH:mm" 
                          options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
NSString *timestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

The time stamp is always in Chinese such as :11月26日 11:20. What I desired is the language and dateformatter is consistent with language setting. Any help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the setting in iPhone: General->International->Region Format. The language and formatter can be set there.